# Responsive number of item in a single row in a grid (SSR/Tailwind)

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, responsive

What would be your strategy to display more or less elements in a line depending on screen size only using css (tailwind classes)

Lets say I wan to display 1 item in mobile, 2 in tablet and 3 in in desktop always in one line.

for now my solution would be something like

```
<div className="grid tablet:grid-cols-2 desktop:grid-cols-3">
  {elements.map((e, i) => (
    <div className={cx(
      i===0 && 'block'
      i===1 && 'hidden tablet:block'
      i===2 && 'hidden desktop:block'
    )} />
  ) )}
</div>
```

but it seems really weird, what would you do if you had the same constraints?

Comment: How would someone with a smaller viewport (note - not using "mobile" "desktop" etc as they are not accurate descriptors) access the data?
Any reason not to wrap?

Comment: @TomPietrosanti Actually its not really important, lets say this is optional data. 
Imagine it is for related products, the first one is relevant and I want to fill the row for more wide screens with some data in order to balance the visual aspect